# JqGrid id and rownumbers conflict

Tags: jquery, jqgrid

I used Guriddo jqGrid JS - v5.0.0 - 2015-09-14

[This is a example trouble](http://2.firepic.org/2/images/2015-10/12/dtaw73wrcfo5.gif)
When I click id = 16 highlights rownum = 16 but id = 15 and etc...

Code:

```
    $("#jqGridEdit").jqGrid({
      url: '/brand/brandFormaQuery.php',
      cellurl:'/editData.php',
      mtype: 'POST',
      datatype: 'json',
      loadtext: "",
      page: 1,
      colModel: [
                    { label: 'id', name: 'id', key: true,hidden: false},
                    { label: 'Name', name: 'brandName',editable:true,hidden: true
                  }
      ],
    cellEdit: true,
    gridview: true,
    deepempty: true,
    gridview: true,
    headertitles: true,
    //autowidth: true,
    //shrinkToFit: false,
    viewsortcols : [true,'horizontal',true],
    width: 1270,
    height: 750,
    rowNum: 200,
    sortable: true,
    rownumbers: true,
    viewrecords: true,
    loadonce: true,
    caption: 'test',
    ignoreCase: true
    });
$('#jqGridEdit').jqGrid('filterToolbar',{searchOnEnter: true, defaultSearch: 'cn'});
   });
```

Comment: You have to include the JSON data from the response from `'/brand/brandFormaQuery.php'`. Do you have the problem directly after loading of the data or after editing? Could you change the URLs to jqGrid to URLs described in [the wiki article](https://github.com/free-jqgrid/jqGrid/wiki/Access-free-jqGrid-from-different-CDNs) and verify that the same problem exist with [free jqGrid](https://github.com/free-jqgrid/jqGrid) too?

Comment: I have this problem after loading. 
I changed URL to cdnjs  free jqGrid 4.9.2 and everything works fine!But why does not work in the new version) I would like to move to a new. Thank you

Comment: You are welcome! Starting with publishing 4.7.1 version directly after 4.7, which changed license agreement, I started developing free jqGrid. I made a lot of changes and two forks: free jqGrid and Guriddo jqGrid JS will be developing in different ways. *So Guriddo jqGrid JS 5.0.0 is not newer as free jqGrid 4.9.2*. I can response only for free jqGrid. Nevertheless it could be the problem in your data. Could you include JSON data returned from the server? You can use [Fiddler](fiddler2.com/Fiddler2/version.asp) or developer tools of IE/Chrome (press F12, choose Network tab) to make HTTP trace.

Comment: Thank for answer, Oleg! It is easier to go to your version.

Answer (score 0):

To analyse and to reproduce the problem one required to have the JSON data. It's important that it should be no id duplicates in the data returned from the server.

I recommend you additionally to try to use [free jqGrid](https://github.com/free-jqgrid/jqGrid) which is **another fork** of jqGrid. You can just use URLs described in [the wiki article](https://github.com/free-jqgrid/jqGrid/wiki/Access-free-jqGrid-from-different-CDNs). Starting with publishing 4.7.1 version directly after 4.7, which changed license agreement, I started developing free jqGrid. Both forks will be developed independent. The version numbers have no relation with which version if newer. I prefer to use 4.*.* version numbers because I try to hold free jqGrid compatible with jqGrid 4.7/4.6 and some other 4.x versions.

If you would have the same problem with free jqGrid then I would suppose that you have some problem (like id duplicates) in the input data. You should use tools like [Fiddler](http://www.telerik.com/fiddler) or Developer Tools of Internet Explorer or Google Chrome (press <kbd>F12</kbd> to start the tools and choose Network tab) to make HTTP trace. The JSON data from the server response should be appended to the text of the question.

If you would have no problem with free jqGrid than some bug could exist in Guriddo jqGrid JS v5.0.0. You can report the problem to Guriddo. You should include JSON data which can be used to reproduce the problem in the bug report.